# Is there anyway I can make this method O(1) in Big-O?

Tags: java, big-o

I will start out by saying that I am completely new to Big-O notation. But as I understand it, my method is not O(1). I am required to make this an O(1), is there anyway to do this?

My method's function is to move elements of an array down one so that element[0] can be changed.

I've just tried changing things around but can't figure out a way to do this without using array.length (which I believe makes it O(n).

```
@Override
public Object enqueueFront(Object element) {
    expandCapacity();

    for (int i = elementData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        elementData[i] = elementData[i - 1];
    }

    return elementData[0] = element;
}
```

I expect the method to make current = current - 1 (see code for more detail) so that a new element can be added to the first element in the array without removing any information from the current array.

Comment: `array.length` is most likely O(1). Looping over your array definitely is not (as far as time-complexity goes).

Comment: I believe that the space complexity to this code is indeed O(1).

Comment: I believe you can do this in O(1) be extending array from both sides and storing the index of the first element. If you are not restricted to arrays, consider using linked list, as suggested by @LachlanLindsay

Comment: You can't make this O(1) in an array-backed data structure. You can make it amortized O(1), though, which is probably sufficient.  Use `ArrayDeque`, which does exactly that.

Comment: _"For efficiency first, last, enqueueRear, enqueueFront, dequeueRear, dequeueFront, clear, size, and isEmpty should all be O(1) operations." - Instructions_ | 


I guess I'll just take the _should_ in the instructions to heart. Thanks guys!

Comment: Shifting array elements cost you O(n). Queue implementation is usually done by circular array, which you keep track of head and tail indices so that head of the queue is not necessarily index 0. It allows you to implement those operations in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you're allowed to change the data structure you're using.

You could use a linked list, this would look something like this

```java
/* 
   enqueue()
   adds newItem to back of this Queue
   pre: none
   post: !isEmpty()
*/
public void enqueue(Object newItem) {
    Node p = new Node(newItem);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = p;
    } else {
        tail.next = p;
        tail = p;  // instead of p = tail;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not something we're allowed to do, sadly. It does help for the next question though. Q1 = Array and Q2 is LinkedList.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't have to expand, you can do all operations in O(1) if you consider the array as circularly closed (i.e. the index 0 follows again the last index). You keep the positions of the first and the last used element in this ring buffer. Make sure, at least one position is always free or you will not be able to distinguish the situation of a completely empty buffer from a completely full one.

When you need to expand, you can arrange things so that the effort is amortized O(1). For example by doubling the array size whenever an expansion is necessary. The expansion itself is an O(n) operation because you have to copy the array contents. But with the doubling strategy the average effort over many operations (and some seldom expansions) is still O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the `expandCapacity` method to expand array form both sides and keep the `index` of the first element, to can do it this way:

```
@Override
public Object enqueueFront(Object element) {
    expandCapacity();

    elementData[indexFirst - 1] = element;
    indexFirst = indexFirst - 1;    

    return;
}
```

This implementation is O(1).

@Henry provided a more detailed explanation of the time complexity of an equivalent approach.